# ASP.net PasswordStrengthRegularExpression to prevent common passwords like "11111" or "123456"

Tags: asp.net, regex, security, passwords

A customer asked me to prevent users from typing common passwords, but permit them to use only alphanumeric passwords.

Do you know a regular expression to use in the built in `PasswordStrengthRegularExpression` option?

**Edit**: I know is pretty vague, and that what I told the client. The definition is something like

- Do not allow the same character more that 3 consecutive times.(1111, 2222, etc)
- Do not allow ascending or descending trends (12345, abcde, 6543, etc.)

Comment: That's a pretty vague request.  If you require at least one letter and one digit, neither of your examples would pass.  Is that good enough for your customer?

Comment: Why the hack only allow alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @Oded: Like 1111, 123456, 654321, password, 123456a, a11111, etc.

Comment: @Marian: not only allow, but permit.

Comment: @Eduardo: Where's the difference? In other words, what reasons exists to forbid people to use punctuation in their passwords?

Comment: @Marian: it's not forbidden, but it's not required.

Comment: Ah sorry, I understood now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's asking way too much from a regex.  You could cover the repeated characters thing easily enough:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1\1)){6,}$
```

But the only way to disallow runs of *sequential* characters would be to enumerate all the possibilities:

```
^(?:(?!123|234|345|456|567|678|789).)*$
```

...ad infinitum.  I think the best you can do is require a complex mix of character types--for example, at least two each of uppercase letters, lowercase letters and digits:

```
^(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})
 (?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})
 (?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})
 (?:([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\1\1)){6,}$
```

That will force the users to be a little creative.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression=" @\"(?=.{6,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})"
```

Validates the password meets the following criteria:

- Is greater than seven characters.
- Contains at least one digit.
- Contains at least one special
  (non-alphanumeric) character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordstrengthregularexpression.aspx

Comment: The `{1,}` are redundant (and might even slow things down): you only care that it matches once, not that it consumes as many copies of the match as possible.  Also, your quotes are messed up; your string starts with `" @\"`, when I think you mean for it to start with `@"`.

Comment: Guh, disregard that—I've never even *used* C#, I just answered a regex question on it and had it on the brain.  Wow.  My bad.

Comment: But the point about the `{1,}` is still valid.  I know that's how it appears in the docs, but it's wrong.  Whoever wrote those docs had very weak regex-fu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a regular expression can handle the requirement, but a function just may be more readable anyway. Something like the below will eliminate anything with three consecutive equal characters or three consecutive characters that are follow an ascending or descending pattern of 1 (letters or numbers).

```
static bool IsPasswordRelativelyStrong(string input)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == input[i - 1] - 1 && input[i - 1] == input[i - 2] - 1)
            return false;
        else if (input[i] == input[i - 1] + 1 && input[i - 1] == input[i - 2] + 1)
            return false;
        else if (input[i] == input[i - 1] && input[i - 1] == input[i - 2])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So given the following array

```
string[] passwords = { "123456", "abcde", "654321", "111223", "11223344" };
```

Only the final one passes. The function could be expanded to consider whether or not you allow and/or require non-alphanumeric characters and whether a password must exceed a minimum length requirement.

Comment: That's what I have in mind. Just didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assert a minimum level of complexity; e. g. "at least one uppercase, one lowercase letter, one digit, minimum length 6 characters, only alphanumeric characters" could be written as

```
 ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^\S*([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10})$"
```