# Restricting Common Passwords like qwerty,123456789 in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want the regular expression to be in model is there a way to do this ?

i read this answer by Anthony Pegram in the following question how can i associate this logic while validating in mvc
[ASP.net PasswordStrengthRegularExpression to prevent common passwords like "11111" or "123456"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992928/asp-net-passwordstrengthregularexpression-to-prevent-common-passwords-like-1111)

Comment: Add a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to your property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest solution would be to have your model inherit from IValidatableObject and implement the Validate method in your model, something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password) == false)
    {
        var passwordValid = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < Password.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Password[i] == Password[i - 1] - 1 && Password[i - 1] == Password[i - 2] - 1)
            {
                passwordValid = false;
            }
            else if (Password[i] == Password[i - 1] + 1 && Password[i - 1] == Password[i - 2] + 1)
            {
                passwordValid = false;
            }
            else if (Password[i] == Password[i - 1] && Password[i - 1] == Password[i - 2])
            {
                passwordValid = false;
            }
        }

        if (!passwordValid)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Your Validation Message Here!", new []{ "Password" });
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to add an extension method with similar logic for your model and then check the results in the controller:

```
if (!model.IsValidPassword())
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your Validation Message Here!");
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression(@"(?=^.{8,30}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;&quot;:;'?/&gt;.&lt;,]).*$",ErrorMessage="Password must have at least 1 small-case letter At least 1 Capital letter At least 1 digit At least 1 special character Length should be between 8-30 characters")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

this will be the code for strong password. Please mark as answer if Helped from this post

Comment: thank you for the answer but this is not what i am looking for

Comment: Can you describe your scenario so that i can improve my answer so that it can help to solve your problem.

Comment: read the answer by Anthony Pegram provided in the link i gave actually i want to use that logic in my model